# printing new column error length of values do not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I converted a list of unix to real datetime, now that I appended it a list (convert), I tried to create a new column in my dataframe.

But I get following the error:

`length of your values do not match length of index.`

Code:

```
convert = []

unixL = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
convert.append(unixL)

df['Real Time'] = convert

print(df)
```

Comment: the convert.append(unixL) is a new line in my code

Comment: and for some reasons the dates are printed as 1970-01-01, when the actually dates are from February 2019

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Real Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
```

What you've done is equivalent to:

```
df['Real Time'] = [pd.to_datetime(df.Time)]
```

The right hand side is a list with 1 element, so it complains because the dataframe doesn't have a length of 1.

Other code that would work (no reason to do them, but it might help your understanding):

```
df['Real Time'] = list(pd.to_datetime(df.Time))
```

or

```
convert = []
unixL = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
convert.extend(unixL)  # extend, not append
df['Real Time'] = convert
```

Comment: thank you! the one thing I can't wrap my head around is that the dates are wrong? the actually dates are from February 2-4 2019 and its printing 1970-01-01

Comment: We'd have to see what df.Time contains to know why.

Comment: 0      1549218465370
1      1549217407480
2      1549217315330
3      1549216513310
4      1549216114340
5      1549215958920
6      1549215901143
7      1549215630453
8      1549215397140
9      1549214980770
10     1549214799200
11     1549214535410
12     1549214445120
13     1549214340540
14     1549214221200
15     1549213878630
16     1549212916600
17     1549212593564
18     1549209268420
19     1549209192574

Comment: It's using the default unit ns, `pandas.to_datetime(1549217407480, unit='ms')` gives the right date.